# Is there a way to find out if something is running as Administrator?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, privileges

Like the question says.... I'm running Server 2008 R2 but ways to find out for other versions of Windows are welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Task Manager` and go to the `Processes` tab and then look at the `User Name` column. Just make sure you tick the `Show processes from all users` checkbox in the bottom left hand corner. (Or first click the UAC prompt in the same place).
[image]

Comment: But when using a desktop version of Windows, how would one tell if they app is running elevated or not?

Comment: All versions of Windows have Task Manager.  Hit CTL-ESC.

Comment: @Surfasb - Control + Escape combination brings up the start menu - I think since XP.